# how can I convert 2 strings to numbers and add them using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have str1, str2 and I want to add them. For example, str1 = '5' and str2 = '2.50000'. I would like to add them together and get 7.50. I have tried many (unsuccessful) variations, the latest is:

```
str1 = "5.00000";
str2 = "2.50000";
new_st1 = parseFloat(str1).toFixed(2);
new_str2 = parseFloat(str2).toFixed(2);
str3 = parseFloat(( new_str1 + new_str2 )).toFixed(2);
```

This produces (absurdly) 5.00.

I would like to get 7.50. And then, of course, to be able to generalize the solution to other more complex additions.

All help very gratefully received.

Comment: In your snippet, the values of `str1` and `str2` are already numbers. The use of `.toFixed()` would be how they become strings.

Comment: Are `str1` and `str2` supposed to be numbers or strings? Your title and second sentence have them as strings, but your example has them as numbers already.

Comment: strings, sorry for ambiguity. 0.0000 is a string even though it looks like a number.

Comment: If they are strings, you should quote them in the example. Many of the answers below assume they are numbers, because that's what you've currently written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
var str1 = 5.00000;
var str2 = 2.50000;
var str3 = ( str1 + str2 ).toFixed(2);
```

They aren't strings, so no need to convert them to floats as they already are. And you should be rounding it after, for accuracy. If they are, just to a `parseFloat()` around the first 2 properties and the 3rd is already fine as it is

Comment: just testing, will revert. Thanks.

Comment: scholar and a gentleman, sir. Thank you works perfectly. Will tick as soon as the system permits.

Answer (score 1):

`parseFloat` returns a number, so you don't need to parse it again. You should perform the math with the numbers, then format (with `toFixed`) at the very end.

```js
var str1 = "5.00000";
var str2 = "2.50000";

var val1 = parseFloat(str1);
var val2 = parseFloat(str2);

var result = val1 + val2;
document.getElementById("result").textContent = result.toFixed(2);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the strings. They work as numbers.

```
str1 + str2
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dga1b1uy/

Answer (score 0):

parseFloat convert string to number.
So, your input should be in string.

Based on your naming convertion, your str1 and str2 should be quoted into string as well..

Here is an example

```
document.write(add('2.5000', '5.000'));

function add(str1, str2){
  var new_str1 = parseFloat(str1);
  var new_str2 = parseFloat(str2);
  var str3 = parseFloat(( new_str1 + new_str2 )).toFixed(2);
  return str3;
}
```